# WireGuard VPN and Uncomplicated Firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I have WireGuard running on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, I use it as a dedicated VPN server. I want UFW on the server too but despite having added the following two rules it does not work.

sudo ufw allow ssh

sudo ufw allow 51820/udp

Once UFW is enabled it does not work. Disable UFW, it works again. All the guides online simply show that all that is needed for it to work is to allow 51820 through.

However some suggest it is to do with forwarding but there seems to be no agreed upon answer that I can find. Using WireGuard with a firewall must be common practice surely?

Comment: do you have any wireguard postup/postdown configuration? if so what is it? for your configuration, you did specify 51820 s the wireguard listen port, right? have you enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl ?

Comment: In /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf I have placed the following that I found online: PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: I've also seen it said to in /etc/default/ufw - to change the DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY to “ACCEPT” but doesn't that open up the firewall to all and sundry?

Comment: In the default policies routing is denied. What does this do specifically? What is the rule syntax to allow routing. I'm sorry but I'm new to firewalls.

Comment: does this help at all: https://askubuntu.com/a/1130516

Comment: I had seen that but the solution seemed to to change the DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY to “ACCEPT” - but then someone questioned it and I am unsure whether I am creating a security risk by doing that, i.e accepting everything.

Comment: No I'm speaking of the more precise rule like `ufw route allow in on eth0 out on eth1 to 12.34.45.67 port 80 proto tcp` as an alternative to setting the default policy.

Comment: I'm all ready to try this, except I'm not sure of the syntax of such a rule. I believe that the interface for WireGuard is wg0. Changing the DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY to “ACCEPT” does work but I've changed it back again to try your suggestion.

Comment: Note that you need to change your PostUp rather than create a rule in UFW. The command in your PostUp is basically setting the default forward policy of Accept that you are worried about. the PostUp event will automatically allow forwarding for your wg0 interface when connected (and then revoke it when disconnecting). since UFW just configures NetFilter the same way iptables does, UFW doesn't really enter into the equation. Sorry, should have detected that sooner.

Comment: Thanks Frank, in the end I achieved my aims, best summed up in this thread - https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/ik6w4h/etcdefaultufw_default_forward_policyaccept/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my aims via this thread that I initiated - https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/ik6w4h/etcdefaultufw_default_forward_policyaccept/

Comment: It would be more helpful if you added the complete steps here, with an explanation.